# Filter by date and time located in different columns in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Data example:

```
Date|Time|Open|High|Low|Close|Volume|NumberOfTrades|BidVolume|AskVolume
2010-12-19|23:01:00.000|1240.0|1240.0|1239.25|1239.75|914|211|0|0
2010-12-19|23:02:00.000|1239.5|1239.75|1239.25|1239.5|509|102|0|0
2010-12-19|23:03:00.000|1239.5|1239.75|1239.25|1239.25|359|63|0|0
2010-12-19|23:04:00.000|1239.25|1239.5|1239.25|1239.5|29|21|0|0
2010-12-19|23:05:00.000|1239.25|1239.75|1239.25|1239.5|158|56|0|0
```

Looking for a right Query to export data to .csv from several tables filtered by start date **and time** and end date **and time**.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE Date BETWEEN Date('2010-12-19') AND Date('2010-12-25');
```

This will select date from `2010-12-19 00:00:00` to `2010-12-25 23:59:59`, but I need exact start and end of date **AND** time, like from `20-12-19 17:00:00` to `20-12-25 08:30:00`.

The solution must work with UNION or any other way to combine those peaces of data from lots of different tables with same structure in one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have date and time stored as `TEXT` in the table, so you must concatenate the 2 columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
WHERE Date || ' ' || Time BETWEEN '2010-12-19 17:00:00.000' AND '2010-12-25 08:30:00.000'
```

I used the milliseconds in the 2 datetimes because they are stored in the column `Time`.
The function `Date()` is not needed.